# startActivity Source not Found

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
public void openOptions()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Game.class);
    //intent.putExtra("razmer", level);
   startActivity(intent);

 // Intent intent=new Intent(this,Options.class);
 // intent.putExtra("level", level);
 // startActivity(intent);
}
```

Output error log:

```
    06-14 10:27:15.049: W/dalvikvm(539): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{your.KrestikiNolikiActivity.namespace/your.KrestikiNolikiActivity.namespace.Game}: 
    java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class your.KrestikiNolikiActivity.namespace.Game; no empty constructor
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class your.KrestikiNolikiActivity.namespace.Game; no empty constructor
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
    06-14 10:27:15.078: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: provide Game.java code.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a blank Constructor to your Game class.

i.e.

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    public Game(){

    }

}
```

So this is happening because you have overridden the constructor

i.e.

```
public Game(String something){
    this.something = something;
}
```

You shouldn't do this in Activities and it will have no effect anyway as you can't instantiate an Activity using the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you Manifest File. Every Class should have an Activity mentioned in the manifest.

```
<activity  android:name=".Game"  
           android:label="@string/app_name">  
</activity>
```